# Trying to edit LUA 5.2 parser C source

Tags: c, lua

I'd like to edit the lua 5.2 source code to allow for an essentially meaningless keyword called "global" which I can place in front of global variable declarations in order to make them more explicit and to cut down on accidental declarations. To be clear, this keyword would get ignored, interpreted as whitespace or otherwise stripped away somehow and would serve solely as syntactic sugar for myself.

Adding custom keywords of existing types is straight forward. The part I'm at a loss for is how to safely edit the parser (via the 5.2 C source code) so that it discards or ignores the new "global" keyword.

Comment: Be advised that, if you do this, you would break any Lua script that uses "global" as an identifier. Also, how would this keyword "cut down on accidental declarations" if nothing is *preventing* those declarations from working.

Comment: @Paul The Lua runtime is *written in C*. Therefore, the OP wants a solution for how to modify the Lua runtime to have that effect on the Lua language. And that solution would itself have to be written in C. So it is a C question.

Comment: @NicolBolas, Thanks for the clarification. He needs to add it to the keyword table and adapt the parser (I assume it has those elements...)

Comment: My global access/declarations are rerouted to a C hashtable via __index/__newindex and so I'm trying to make the order in which entries are actually instantiated extra explicit.